# In Splashscreen Activity inside I implemented the interface. How to send data of interface to multiple Activity in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, interface

Interface class:

```
interface MyCustomInterface {
     fun get_msg( str: String)

}
```

SplashScreen Activity:

```
class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity(),MyCustomInterface {
    override fun get_msg(str: String) {

    }

val socket=MysocketIO(this)
    }
```

*MySocketIO class* where I  added the data to interface from server:

```
class MysocketIO(var mainActivity: SplashActivity) : Thread() {
    fun enable_data_event():Boolean {
        try {
            data_event_registered.set(true)
            socket!!.on(this.data_event_id, object : Emitter.Listener {
                override fun call(vararg args: Any) {
                    receive_data_queue.add(args[0] as String)
                    data_recieved.set(true)
                    mainActivity.get_msg(receive_data_queue.peek())
                }
            })
            return true
        }
        catch (ex : java.lang.Exception){
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

How to get data from SplashScreen to another activity?

Comment: try RxObservables & Observers or try EventBus. that will help you alot

Answer (score 0):

Try to create one global veriable to store interface data after then pass intent to activity..
like ..

```
class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity(),MyCustomInterface{
var data=""
override fun get_msg(str: String) {
    data=str
}
```

after when to start any activity to pass data into intent like..

```
intent.putString(key,data)
```